# aws ios sdk - Issue downloading images from s3

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-ios

I am trying to download the images from my s3 bucket using iOS sdk (swift), but i am always getting `access-denied` error

`Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSS3ErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)" UserInfo={HostId=asadadadadadad=, Message=Access Denied, Code=AccessDenied, RequestId=A467438974F8127B}]`

It works juts fine with the uploads, when i don't use any ACL settings. If i set the ACL

```
 let uploadRequest = AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest()
 uploadRequest.ACL = AWSS3ObjectCannedACL.AuthenticatedRead
```

both upload & download fails.

below are my cognito & IAM policies

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
    "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::yimages/*"]
    },{
    "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::yimages"]
    }
  ]
}
```

and

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"AddCannedAcl",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
     "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::yimages/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

i am sure this is something todo with the policies, but i cant figure out what.. whats puzzling me is how come the upload works but the download??

any help is much appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

1. GetObject & PutObject refer to actions on objects within the bucket & do not apply to the bucket (arn:aws:s3:::yimages). For the bucket itself, you need to provide Bucket actions like below :

> ```
> "Action": [
>             "s3:GetBucketLocation",
>             "s3:ListBucket",
>             "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
>         ]
> ```

2. You could try adding similar policy into the explicit 'Bucket Policy' section of the 'Permissions' tab to specify Bucket & Object level permissions